# Give an example to a function of 2 variables that has a minimum at $(x_1,y_1)$ and a maximum at $(x_2,y_2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to give an example of a function $f(x,y)$ with a local minimum at $(2,3)$ and a local maximum at $(3,4)$.

Here's what I know about $f$:
$$f_x(2)=f_x(3)=0
\\f_y(3)=f_y(4)=0 
\\D(2,3), D(3,4)>0
\\f_{xx}(3,4)<0
\\f_{xx}(2,3)>0
$$
How do I continue from there to actually construct the function?

Comment: It seems to me that you are making the problem too complicated by assuming that your function is $C^2$ (unless you were explicitly told that your function should be twice differentiable?).  Why not something like $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if $(x,y)=(2,3)$,} \\ 1 & \text{if $(x,y)=(3,4)$,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise?} \end{cases} $$

Comment: There seem to be some typos. $f_x$ and $f_y$  should both depend on two variables. And what is $D$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Apparently that's good enough. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=-\int(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\text{d}x\int(y-y_1)(y-y_2)\text{d}y$$is $C^\infty$, has a local minimum at $(x_1,y_1)$, and has a local maximum at $(x_2,y_2)$.